# In Apache Spark's Scala API, is there a difference between using one single quote and $"" notation?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, syntax

I have noticed two different notation styles when referencing columns (in this case in a select statement). Is there a functional difference between the two?

```
val df = spark.read.table("mytable").select('column1,'column2)
```

vs.

```
val df = spark.read.table("mytable").select($"column1",$"column2")
```

I haven't been able to find anything that really explains the difference or if there is a standard.

Comment: Polling for community preferences seems slightly off-topic. Maybe you should reformulate your question with more emphasis on the "functional difference".

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Fair point. I removed that part from the initial language. I was somewhat interested if there was a standard, but the key point really is whether there is a functional difference between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using any of `'column1,'column2` or `$"column1",$"column2"`, the returned value is going to be `ColumnName(column1), ColumnName(column2)` which happens to be a sub class of `Column()` that is one of the expected types to `select`. However, their implementations are different.

In order to use the symbols, an import `import spark.implicits._` to be included in the application where `spark` is a `SparkSession` object. The import ensures that following implicits are available and in-scope.

From Spark code,

```
   @Experimental
      object implicits extends SQLImplicits with Serializable {
        protected override def _sqlContext: SQLContext = SparkSession.this.sqlContext
      }
```

`spark.implicits` extends `SQLImplicits`

```
package org.apache.spark.sql

abstract class SQLImplicits extends LowPrioritySQLImplicits {

   ...

  /**
   * Converts $"col name" into a [[Column]].
   *
   * @since 2.0.0
   */
  implicit class StringToColumn(val sc: StringContext) {
    def $(args: Any*): ColumnName = {
      new ColumnName(sc.s(args: _*))
    }
  }

  ...

   /**
   * An implicit conversion that turns a Scala `Symbol` into a [[Column]].
   * @since 1.3.0
   */
  implicit def symbolToColumn(s: Symbol): ColumnName = new ColumnName(s.name)

}
```

When using `$column1`, the `$` method in implicit class `StringToColumn` is invoked that converts a `String` to a `ColumnName` instance.

`'` is a scala symbol. In order to use it `import spark.implicits._` is not required. however, to a convert a Scala symbol to a `Column`, the import is needed. When using this symbol, the implicit method `symbolToColumn` will get executed and returns a `ColumnName` instance. Note that `'column1` is same as `Symbol("column1")` in Scala.

From `org.apache.spark.sql.Column.scala`, `ColumnName` is a subclass of `Column`. so the returned objects from `$` and `'` can be used in DataFrame/Dataset `select` methods.

```
/**
 * A convenient class used for constructing schema.
 *
 * @since 1.3.0
 */
@InterfaceStability.Stable
class ColumnName(name: String) extends Column(name) {
    ...
}
```